# Saving/Updating Existing XML with XML generated in Javascript to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

Hi all I am trying to make a CMS in which you use little form inputs to add and remove data from an XML spread sheet. Now here's the catch. I have to do the entire thing in Javascript or jQuery (+ plugins). I have the XML read into the web page and when content is edited and the "save" button is clicked it the javascript will generate it's own XML and my problem is trying to overwrite or append the existing XML file with the updated one that I just generated.

I am not entirely sure if javascript can do this because it's client side but I have to do this using PHP. I thing AJAX must have some sort of functionality for this but I can not find it.

Anyone have an idea as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I found javascript to work great for reading & editing XML I had to use PHP to take form values and format it into XML and then save it to the server.